# vue-slider-component completely invisible

Tags: vue.js, frontend, vue-component

I'm making a Vue web app wity vue-cli that uses NightCatSama's vue-slider-component, but for some reason it seems the slider is totally invisible. Strangely, selecting DOM elements in the Elements tab does highlight them, and if I click where the dots are supposed to be on this invisible slider, the component's data **do** change as if I was dragging dots I could see

Here is the template/JS of my app (commenting out the whole style had no effect)

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <vue-slider v-model="dots"></vue-slider>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import VueSlider from "vue-slider-component";

export default {
  name: "app",
  components: { VueSlider },
  data: function() { return {"dots": [0, 50]} },
}
</script>
```

The one other odd thing is if I go in the Vue panel of the developer tools, the component's name seems to be "E", not  "VueSlider"

Answer (score 0):

Found the bug. I just forgot to import a style for the component